# CSS tiles positioning

Tags: html, css, less

Hello I'm working on website that use tiles like this:
[image]

As you can see almost everything is ready, but there is one tile lower than others. I want to put it in the right place, but nothin came to my mind now. And I am blocked with job, unless it will work perfectly.

My code Less:

```
.tile-loop(@index: 1) when (@index <= 6){
  .tile-loop(@index + 1);
  &.t@{index}x1{
    width: (@index * @tile-width) + ((@index - 1) * 2 * @tile-margin);
    height: @tile-height;
  }
  &.t@{index}x2{
    width: (@index * @tile-width) + ((@index - 1) * 2 * @tile-margin);
    height: 2 * @tile-height + 2 * @tile-margin;
  }
  &.t@{index}x3{
    width: (@index * @tile-width) + ((@index - 1) * 2 * @tile-margin);
    height: 3 * @tile-height + 4 * @tile-margin;
  }
  &.t@{index}x4{
    width: (@index * @tile-width) + ((@index - 1) * 2 * @tile-margin);
    height: 4 * @tile-height + 6 * @tile-margin;
  }
  &.t@{index}x5{
    width: (@index * @tile-width) + ((@index - 1) * 2 * @tile-margin);
    height: 5 * @tile-height + 8 * @tile-margin;
  }
  &.t@{index}x6{
    width: (@index * @tile-width) + ((@index - 1) * 2 * @tile-margin);
    height: 6 * @tile-height + 10 * @tile-margin;
  }
}
.tiles {
    padding: 40px 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid @color-black;
    .grid {
      margin-left: -10px;
      margin-right: -10px;
      display: block;
      .tile {
        float: left;
        margin: @tile-margin;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        .tile-loop();
      }
      .clear {
        clear: both;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="tiles">
            <div class="grid">
                <div class="tile t3x4" style="background: red;"></div>
                <div class="tile t3x2" style="background: blue;"></div>
                <div class="tile t3x2" style="background: green;"></div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div class="tile t2x3" style="background: red;"></div>
                <div class="tile t2x1" style="background: blue;"></div>
                <div class="tile t2x2" style="background: green;"></div>
                <div class="tile t2x2" style="background: green;"></div>
                <div class="tile t1x1" style="background: green;"></div>
                <div class="tile t1x1" style="background: green;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Please help.

Comment: Why not use a grid layout CSS framework that has already solved this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to resolve it is to simply just move up the div that is out of place, using positioning:

```
.up {
    position:absolute;
    top: -@tile-height;
}
```

And then add the .up-class to the div you need to move up

Comment: This solution maybe isn't beautyfull, but in my app work perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this kind of layout on CSS only. There are special JS solutions:

- http://masonry.desandro.com/
- http://sapegin.github.io/jquery.mosaicflow/

Answer (score 2):

This type of layout is called `Masonry layout`, Masonry is another grid layout but it will fill out the whitespace caused by the difference height of elements.

[jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) is one of jQuery plugin to create masonry layout.

Alternatively, you can use CSS3 `columns`. But for now jQuery based plugin is the best choice since there is compatibility issue with CSS3 column

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/Jdbzvx)

Answer (score 0):

For your layout I would use floating "columns" containers and inside the elements you need so you will be sure there won't be your structure problems.

Basically I would change your html and css to this (sorry, no `less`):

```css
body {margin:0;}
* {box-sizing:border-box;}
.column {
    float:left;
}
.x1 {
    width:calc(50% - 10px);
    margin-right:20px;
}
.x2 {
    width:calc(50% - 10px);
}
.x3 {
    width:calc(33.3333% - 13.33333px);
    margin-right:20px;
}
.x4 {
    width:calc(33.3333% - 13.33333px);
    margin-right:20px;
}
.x5 {
    width:calc(33.3333% - 13.33333px);
}
.t3x4, .t2x3 {
    height:300px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    width:100%;
}
.t3x2 {
    height:calc(150px - 10px);
    margin-bottom:20px; 
    width:100%;
}
.t2x1 {
    height:calc(100px - 10px);
    margin-bottom:20px; 
    width:100%;
}
.t2x2 {
    height:calc(200px - 10px);
    margin-bottom:20px; 
    width:100%;
}
.t1x1, .right {
    height:calc(100px - 10px);
    margin-bottom:20px; 
    width:calc(50% - 10px);
    margin-right:20px;
    float:left;
}
.right {margin-right:0px;}
```

```html
<div class="tiles">
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="column x1">
            <div class="tile t3x4" style="background: red;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="column x2">
            <div class="tile t3x2" style="background: blue;"></div>
            <div class="tile t3x2" style="background: green;"></div>            
        </div> 
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="column x3">    
            <div class="tile t2x3" style="background: red;"></div>
        </div>    
        <div class="column x4">    
            <div class="tile t2x1" style="background: blue;"></div>
            <div class="tile t2x2" style="background: green;"></div>
        </div>    
        <div class="column x5">    
            <div class="tile t2x2" style="background: green;"></div>
            <div class="tile t1x1" style="background: green;"></div>
            <div class="tile t1x1 right" style="background: green;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/Lh7e9a43/1/)** example